# Remove space in one column in .CSV - Python/Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is how my "new_plates.csv" looks like -

```
TT59 TRI,"Black,Thomas,Mr"
HY63 YOJ,"Smith,Simon,Mr"
YY36 DPM,"Paul & Clare,Mr & Mrs"
```

Here is Python code - I'm first converting "plates.txt" file to "plates.csv" file, then filter unused columns to "new_plates.csv" and removing old "plates.csv". This works just fine, but then I want to remove spaces from plate numbers, but keep them in names. What's not working.

```py
import os
import subprocess
import pandas
import pandas as pd

subprocess.call("sudo csvformat -t /home/pi/scripts/plates.txt >> /home/pi/scripts/plates.csv", shell=True)


f=pd.read_csv("plates.csv")

keep_col = [11,13]
new_f = f[keep_col]
new_f.to_csv("new_plates.csv", index=False)

new_f[1]= new_f[1].str.replace(" ", "")

subprocess.call("sudo rm /home/pi/scripts/plates.csv", shell=True)

print(new_f)
```

Can't figure out, how to write this line correctly

```py
new_f[1]= new_f[1].str.replace(" ", "")
```

I want to look it like this - Plate Numbers without spaces

```
TT59TRI,"Black,Thomas,Mr"
HY63YOJ,"Smith,Simon,Mr"
YY36DPM,"Paul & Clare,Mr & Mrs"
```

Thank you

Comment: Your two calls to `subprocess.call()` are not needed.  `pd.read_csv()` can handle your file given the proper arguments.  File removal can be accomplished one of two ways: `os.unlink('/home/pi/scripts/plates.csv')` or `pathlib.Path('/home/pi/scripts/plates.csv').unlink()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.split().apply("".join)`

**Ex:**

```
df=pd.read_csv("plates.csv", names=["plates", "name"])
df["plates"] = df["plates"].str.split().apply("".join)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    plates                   name
0  TT59TRI        Black,Thomas,Mr
1  HY63YOJ         Smith,Simon,Mr
2  YY36DPM  Paul & Clare,Mr & Mrs
```

Comment: `df['plates'] = df['plates'].str.replace(' ', '')` is more direct, no?

Answer (score -1):

First, no need to  convert txt to csv as pandas can handle txt too. Second,

```
new_f[1] = [plate.replace(" ", "") for plate in new_f[1]]
```

Comment: Works, but manual iteration when you don't have to is really bad form for `pandas`.